# Make webpack build fast

Tags: webpack

I just get start to learn [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), and I feel its building performance is not very good, even though my testing project only contains few lines of code. How to optimize the building performance of webpack.

Comment: Could you try [happypack](https://github.com/amireh/happypack) and see if it fits your use case?

Comment: Does your few lines of code depend on any npm modules? Also, are you using watch mode? https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#watch-mode

Comment: @riscarrott Yes it does depend on other npm modules, and I not using watch mode.

Comment: @theJian Webpack is able to take advantage of heavy caching in watch mode which makes rebuilds during development very fast. You can expect a fresh build to take 20 seconds + which I don't think is unreasonable?

Comment: Did you exclude the `node_modules` from bundling? You can do that, with adding `exclude: /node_modules/` to the loader-definition.

Comment: @TN1ck I've added `include`

Answer (score 1):

you should use watchmode for this purpose, it will only recompile the changes in the sourcefiles.  It usually takes me 1 secound in a pretty big project.

Run:

```
webpack --watch
```

In any commandline, or for example the visual studio task runner explorer